# Performance analysis

Tags: rust

Looking at a very simple program, how to figure out where the CPU is spent:

```
use mmap::*;
use crc::{crc32, Hasher32};

use std::cmp::min;
use std::env::args;
use std::fs::File;
use std::fs::metadata;
use std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd;
use std::slice::from_raw_parts;
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
   let filename = args().nth(1).unwrap();
   let t0 = Instant::now();
   let file = File::open(String::from(&filename[..]))?;
   let fd = file.as_raw_fd();
   let fs = metadata(filename)?;
   let sz = fs.len() as usize;

   let mut offset: usize = 0;
   let mut c32 = crc32::Digest::new(crc32::IEEE);
   while offset < sz {
      let rem = sz - offset;
      let rem = min(rem, 1024 * 1024);

      let map = MemoryMap::new(rem, &[MapOption::MapFd(fd),
                                      MapOption::MapReadable,
                                      MapOption::MapOffset(offset)]).
                map_err(|e| std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, e))?;
      let buf = map.data();
      c32.write(unsafe { from_raw_parts(buf, rem) });
      offset += rem;
   }
   println!("{:08x} in {:.3}", c32.sum32(), t0.elapsed().as_secs());
   Ok(())
}
```

This is intended to memory-map the file provided on command line, and compute the CRC32 of it. I am not looking for other implementations that may achieve that, because my intention is to practice interactions with `libc` functions.

The program appears to operate correctly, but consumes much more time and CPU than equivalent Go or Java program I wrote, even though I think it is compiled with optimisations:

Cargo.toml:

```
[profile.dev]
opt-level = 3

[package]
name = "mmap"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Gee"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

mmap = "~0.1.1"
crc = "^1.0.0"
```

Mac OSX, SSD, executing Go and Rust programs in various order to eliminate the impact of "cold" file buffers and "warm" buffers - produces about 4 seconds cold for Go, and less than a second warm run for Go, but always 30+ seconds for Rust. Tried `cargo build --release`, too. CPU utilisation by Rust program is substantially higher, too (eg 25% for Go, 80+% for Rust). I would expect CPU utilisation to come mostly from CRC-32 computation and copying the file contents between some buffers. The difference is then in something that causes Rust to do extra work here.

Go program scanning a 1GB XML file using the same method, `syscall.Mmap`, mapping 1MB at a time:

```
$ ../a ~/demo/dest.xml 
a772d8c4 in 3.978
```

Cargo run:

```
$ cargo run ~/demo/dest.xml 
    Finished dev [optimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.13s
     Running `target/debug/mmap /Users/ololo/demo/dest.xml`
a772d8c4 in 33
```

---

In the comments there was a request to show a Java program. Here's the Go program that can be seen to read that file in 3.9 seconds:

```
package main

import(
   "fmt"
   "hash/crc32"
   "os"
   "syscall"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   t0 := time.Now()
   fn := os.Args[1]
   fd, err := os.Open(fn)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Couldn't open %s", err)
      return
   }
   defer fd.Close()

   fi, err := fd.Stat()
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Couldn't stat: %s", err)
      return
   }

   sz := fi.Size()

   cksum := crc32.NewIEEE()
   var off int64

   off = 0
   for sz > off {
      rem := 1024 * 1024
      if sz - off < int64(rem) {
         rem = int(sz - off)
      }
      data, err := syscall.Mmap(int(fd.Fd()), off, rem, syscall.PROT_READ, syscall.MAP_SHARED)
      if err != nil {
         fmt.Printf("Couldn't mmap at %d", off)
         return
      }
      off += int64(rem)
      n, err := cksum.Write(data)
      if err != nil || n != len(data) {
         fmt.Printf("Somehow could not cksum %d", len(data))
         return
      }

      syscall.Munmap(data)
   }

   fmt.Printf("%x in %.3f\n", cksum.Sum32(), time.Now().Sub(t0).Seconds())
}
```

Comment: 1. `cargo run --release`; 2. Your abuse of `unsafe` when you could've done without robbed the compiler of a few valuable optimizations even with `--release`; 3. You didn't actually show us the java code, so we can't even tell you whether you benchmarked the same thing.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld 1. I tried that; 2. It's not abuse, it appears to be necessary to convert `ptr` to a `slice` - but more importantly, how to confirm, or how to get around not using `unsafe`?; 3. I thought of keeping the question short and focused on how to understand where Rust spends time. I've updated the question with the Go program that can be seen to run in 4 seconds, and consume 25% CPU.

Comment: For #1, why did you report the unoptimized run time in the question? Not that I'm calling results in shade or anything, but it's a bit misleading.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Because I want to find out from the commenters what I am doing wrong. To me the compilation results show it is "optimized". Is that misleading output from `rustc`? We can also exclude the suspicion that the file gets mapped differently, because the result is consistently 10x worse no matter in which order I execute the Go program. (eg Go first - 3 seconds - Rust - 30+ seconds - Go again - less than a second (the file is buffered by the OS) - Rust again - 30+ seconds) Plus the CPU utilisation is trying to tell me something.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Also, am I using the wrong packages for the job? I am using https://docs.rs/mmap/0.1.1/mmap/struct.MemoryMap.html for `mmap`, I looked at the source for the mapping - it looks a fairly straightforward use of `libc` functions.

Comment: If nobody has touched this question before I get home, I'll dig into it; I don't have the tools to get through this properly on this laptop. Profiling should turn up a few things, as the 25% CPU usage would be very noticeable.

Comment: I've compiled this on rustc 1.37 and run it on a linux laptop with a 1GB random file: the code reports a runtime of 2 seconds and I don't see the cpu usage you describe (except if running a non-release build)

Comment: @JussiKukkonen that was 1.36 and Mac OSX. Same result after `rustup update` upgraded to 1.38.0, `cargo build --release` with `opt-level=3` for `profile.release`. But glad to see it is not something dumb with the way I am doing it, just possibly something Mac-specific.

Comment: If anyone is watching, here's the update. Adding time measurements of function calls reveals there's something wrong with that `mmap` crate after all: 
```
a772d8c4 in 37.119
Time breakdown:
mmap: 32.859
.data(): 0.000
from_raw_parts: 0.000
crc32.write: 4.233
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's OS specifics here.

```
let map = MemoryMap::new(
    rem,
    &[
        MapOption::MapFd(fd),
        MapOption::MapNonStandardFlags(libc::MAP_SHARED),
        MapOption::MapReadable,
        MapOption::MapOffset(offset),
    ],
)
.map_err(|e| std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, e))?;
```

The crate I am using does not expose access to `MAP_SHARED` explicitly for some reason, and given the comments to the question it probably does not make a difference on Linux. Mac OSX appears to treat `MAP_SHARED` differently from when that flag is not specified, making `mmap` syscall substantially slower. When `MAP_SHARED` is specified, it is back to about 3 seconds for the "warm" run on Mac.